# Update realm table

Tags: java, android, realm

I was just wondering if what I'm doing to update a entire table in realm is the correct safe approach. I receive a list of conversations from the server and update my db like this:

```
@Override
public void saveConversations(final List<Conversation> conversations) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {

            // Remove all conversations and replace with the one passed in
            // Realm does not support cascade deletes. Remove messages as well
            // https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1104
            realm.delete(Conversation.class);
            realm.delete(Message.class);

            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(conversations);
        }
    });
}
```

Conversation.java has a RealmList of messages inside:

```
public class Conversation extends RealmObject {

    private RealmList<Message> messages = new RealmList<>();
```

This works, I couldn't find any bugs with it but it does not look particularly elegant. What if `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(conversations);` goes wrong? I would lose all my data.

Anyways, I know this is not very probable, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing things.

PS: bear in mind that I delete everything from the db because I don't want conversations in my db that don't exist in the server anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that you're executing a transaction, so if `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` fails, then the transaction is **cancelled**, which means you wouldn't lose all your data.

Personally, I used to go with the "delete all" approach, and if you can clear out all tables then it won't cause issues, but if you have a third table where you're referring to `Conversation` and `Message` (for example `User.class`), you'd be invalidating all relations. So I personally prefer to merge like this.

- merging data and removing all data that's not in the list you've saving

.

```
public class Contact {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    @Index
    private String name;

    @Index
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Index
    private boolean isBeingSaved; // this line is important

    //getters, setters
}
```

Then merge:

```
// background thread
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    final List<Contact> contacts = getContacts();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(contacts);
            realm.where(Contact.class)
                 .equalTo(ContactFields.IS_BEING_SAVED, false) // compile 'dk.ilios:realmfieldnameshelper:1.1.0'
                 .findAll()
                 .deleteAllFromRealm(); // delete all non-saved data
                        // in your case, this is where you'd handle the cascading too though manually
            for(Contact realmContact : realm.where(Contact.class).findAll()) { // realm 0.89.0+
                realmContact.setIsBeingSaved(false); // reset all save state
            }
        }
    });
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware the transaction would be reverted if it didn't succeed, that's a pretty cool feature. Thanks to you for sharing your approach1

Comment: Yeah, it's what `executeTransaction()` does, otherwise it'd be manually `realm.beginTransaction()`, `realm.commitTransaction()` and `realm.cancelTransaction()`. Examples often neglect `realm.cancelTransaction()` on error, despite it being very important to cancel the write transaction on failure.